# Mail PEAR not found

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm having problems including PEAR Mail package in my php web application. Every time I get

> PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required.

I'm 100% PEAR Mail is installed in server since my other application is using it and it's working without problem. I tried setting permissions, searching google and every thing I know. Does anyone know some additional special stuff I should check?

Comment: Is there any difference between the two applications?

Comment: Please post the line of code that throws that error, and possibly some lines around it if they are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your include path is not set correctly. Please follow the installation setup check instructions at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

It may also be that you're on a windows system where including `mail.php` works, but on a linux system with case sensitive file systems you need to use the real filename, `Mail.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Install the following on linux, then try

```
sudo pear install Mail-1.4.1
sudo pear install Net_SMTP
```